# How to get Forex data from the Finazon API?

Tags: forex, finazon

I registered and try to get Forex data via next request:

api.finazon.io/v1.0/time_series?ticker=EUR/USD&publisher=forex&interval=1m&apikey=my_apikey

But have the next response:

```json
{
   "status":400,
   "error":{
      "code":"INVALID_PUBLISHER",
      "message":"The publisher 'forex' you have specified is unrecognized or unsupported.",
      "more_info":"https://support.finazon.io/en/articles/7922475-api-errors#h_022b7bfaad"
   }
}
```

How to call API in right way?

Answer (score 0):

For forex, need to call API with the next params: `&publisher=finazon&market=forex`

https://api.finazon.io/v1.0/time_series?ticker=EUR/USD&publisher=finazon&interval=1m&market=forex&apikey=your_apikey